# Is there an Windows 8 API that we can leverage to read barcodes?

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am looking  for an HTML/javascript sample that I can use on a windows 8 app to read barcodes.

There are a couple apps that can read barcodes in the store. However, they must be using something like C# because I was not able to find a sample that uses HTML/Javascript to be able to read barcodes. I know barcodes have specific requirements, but I am just looking for a sample here.

Does anyone know where I can find a simple sample?

Thank You for reading.

Comment: keep in mind C# could still be an option since you could use a portable class library and consume it from your HTML/JavaScript app

Answer (score 2):

Yes - ZXing is an open source library for reading 1D and 2D barcodes. There are a few ports including one for WinRT which can be found here: http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/. You should be able to reference this in your application as a component and call it from WinJS.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can check this link:
http://www.activebarcode.com/ - Provides a barcode API for your APP. It can also be used with VB.net, C#. It also provides you a different kinds of barcode formats.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

I made a lib for WinRT using ZXing & Imaging SDK.
It works well  (but does not include any additional focus feature).
https://github.com/stepheUp/VideoScanZXing4WP81
There is a lib and a sample app that you can try.
It works for barcodes and QRCode (barcode by default but just change the optional parameter in the scan function code to use QRCode)

Hope it helps,
Stéphanie